# Angular dynamic values not showing after deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, angularjs

I have a Rails app with Angularjs parts in it. This app works fine on my local machine, but after deploying to Heroku all the dynamic angular data values are not visible, I only see the handlebars, e.g. `{{groundvisit.match_nr}}` instead of the actual value `123`.

I have a gut feeling it has to do with the asset pipeline, my application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fancybox
//= require jquery.fancybox.pack
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require general
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular/angular-resource
//= require angular/base
//= require angular/controllers/groundvisits_ctrl
//= require_tree .
```

Any clues what is going wrong here?

Update: I know that because of compressing the assets variable names might be hampered with, so I use them like this:

```
@app = angular.module('MyGroundhops', ['ngResource'])

@GroundvisitsCtrl = @app.controller 'GroundvisitsCtrl', ["$scope", "$resource", ($scope, $resource) ->
```

Comment: I dont know about ruby n all, but look at the network requests using firebug and see if all scripts are being resolved, then work your way backward to fix script loading issues.

Comment: sounds a bit daft but did you `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` by any chance? And further more if you did. Then did you also test your application in production mode before deploying to heroku?

Comment: I did no local assets precompiling

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A temporary solution (as long as you understand the tradeoff) is to add this to your /config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Sprockets::LazyCompressor.new { Uglifier.new(mangle: false)}
```

I got this from the railscast #405.